# Nodejs sequelize many to many relation ship mapping in single table with add, update, delete

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have multiple type of posts (Post, Product, Image) and one category option that has multiple categories. I want to assign multiple category to post but i don't want to create more than one table for store relationship information with post type.

Comment: Please update the question with your code which you write so far.

Comment: It is very simple we have post, page, images and category - like xyz, abc, jkl.

I want to associate all post, image, page with category using belong to many.